# cucumber grails - feature with unimplemented steps still passes

Tags: grails, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I have very recently started trying out BDD using cucumber and grails. I'm following a tutorial from the cucumber recipes book, and have created a feature but not yet created the step definitions to implement the test.

```
  Feature: Furious Fowl Game
    @integration
    Scenario: New Game
      Given: I see 3 buildings
      When: I slingshot a bird
      Then: I should see 2 buildings
```

When I run `grails test-app :cucumber`, I am expecting the test to fail to indicate that the steps have not been implemented, however the test result is success:

```
Furious Fowl Game
A single test executed without a single error or failure! 
System output

Feature: Furious Fowl Game
  Scenario: New Game # Game.feature:4
    Given: I see 3 buildings
    When: I slingshot a bird
    Then: I should see 2 buildings
```

I'm sure this is probably something obvious, but I'm stumped. Please let me know if you need to see anything I've not included above.

Comment: Grails – version 2.2.2
Cucumber plugin – 0.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just down to the version of the grails cucumber plugin.

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for the plugin 0.7.0 adds handling pending steps and reports them as errors, so have updated to 0.8.0.